# MySQL: using YEAR_MONTH

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpmyAdmin suggested an autocompleted function `YEAR_MONTH()` in the Query Editor that I can't find anywhere online. It would be awesome if this function existed.

Does it? If yes, how would one use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it isn't a valid *function*, `YEAR_MONTH` is valid SQL. For instance:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2009-07-02 01:02:03');
```

See also the discussion at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11877

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT YEAR('2015-09-30 11:19:00');
```

**or**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2015-09-30 11:19:00','%y:%c');
```

**or**

```
SELECT '2015-09-30 11:19:00' + INTERVAL '2:2' YEAR_MONTH;
```

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote the first 2 queries. And can you explain the 3rd? So YEAR_MONTH is some kind of parameter then?